# Swift - Realm mobile platform today extension

Tags: ios, swift, realm, ios-app-group, realm-mobile-platform

I'm building a Notes app with **today extension**.

I want to link my app's data with today widget using **App Group**.
To do this, I have to change the default **realm**'s fileURL to **App Group** URL.
Without **syncConfiguration** it works very well, but when I use this, the default **realm**'s fileURL did not changed.

So my Questions is how can I change **Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration.fileURL** using realm mobile platform!!!

```
let file = FileManager.default
let directory: NSURL = file.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: "group.com.myapp")! as NSURL
let realmPath = directory.appendingPathComponent("default.realm")


Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = Realm.Configuration(
     fileURL: realmPath,
     syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(
        user: user,
        realmURL: URL(string: "realm://myserver:9080/~/myNote")!
     ),
     objectTypes: [realmNote.self, Tag.self]
)


self.realm = try! Realm()
```

please help!!!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a sync configuration on the `Configuration` object, you cannot set a custom file URL. The sync configuration, file URL, and in-memory identifier are mutually exclusive settings. This is by design.

If you need it to work otherwise, please feel free to file a ticket at our [GitHub repository](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues), and we'll take a look.